# Как отключить Debugger в Google Chrome?

Tags: вёрстка, google-chrome

При использовании инструментов разработчика вылетает проект и жутко глючит, потом пишет что Debugger остановлен и т.д. Наверное я его случайно включил. Кто знает как его выключить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

собственно после вызова инструментов разработчика и включается отладчик, по сути это всё полностью и есть отладчик. Когда вы переходите по вкладкам, то задействуются разные модули отладчика.
вариантов решения вижу несколько:

- открыть в другом chrome-подобном браузере проект и посмотреть как там себя ведёт отладка
- использовать по одной вкладе в инструментах, что бы определить где происходит ошибка

Comment: Не совсем так..

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло включение blackboxing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы пишете о включении blackboxing, а на картинке blackboxing будет остановлен. Могли бы вы дать более подробный ответ?

Comment: Как отключить? Напишите, пожалуйста, для тупых
Где вызывается остановка blackboxing?

Comment: @Зиночка правой кнопкой мышкой, на код js (после открытия панели для программиста), там выйдет меню ваших breakpoint, вы можете удалить оттуда https://i.stack.imgur.com/txyb9.png там же есть список всех точек остановки